# Moving an array of shape object using timer and a start button - Java

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, timer, shapes

I'm having trouble getting each element in my shape array to move when its move method is called. I want the panel to be redrawn every 10 milliseconds with their Shapes in new positions. I want to do this when my start button is pressed/timer is started. I also want to be able to stop this using my timer and Jbutton stop. Feel free to ask me to explain this more :) Cheers for your help :)

**Here is my Shape class**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;

public class Shape{
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private Color colour;
  static final int moveX = 1;
  static final int moveY = 1;

    public void move (){
    x = x + moveX;
    y = y + moveY;

  }


  /**randomRange method that takes in two parameters, low and high
    * Creates a Random generator that returns a random integer within the low and high range set
    */
    public class RandomRange{
  public int randomRange(int low, int high){
    Random generator = new Random();
    return generator.nextInt(high-low) + low;

  }
    }
  /**Shape constructor which sets data fields to random values within a range
    */
  public Shape (){

    RandomRange r = new RandomRange();
    this.width = r.randomRange(10, 30); 
    this.height = width;
    this.x = r.randomRange(0,(400-width));
    this.y = r.randomRange(0,(400-height));


    int red = r.randomRange(0,255);
    int green = r.randomRange(0,255);
    int blue = r.randomRange(0,255);
    colour = new Color (red, green, blue); //creates a new Color colour consisting of random values from red,green and blue

  }
  /**Display method that gets passed a graphics object
    *sets graphics object g to colour and fills oval with the random values set in constructor Shape
    */
  public void display(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(colour);
    g.fillOval(x,y,width,height);

  }
} //end of class
```

**The start of my ShapePanel class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapePanel extends JPanel{
  Shape [] shapes = new Shape [20]; //array of 20 elements that have references to as many as 20 Shape objects
  DrawingPanel drawPanel;
  private int count;
  private JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
  private JTextField showNum = new JTextField(2);
  private JLabel countLabel = new JLabel("Count"); 
  private JButton addShape = new JButton("Add Shape");
  private JButton start = new JButton("Start");
  private JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
  Timer timer;
  private final int DELAY = 10;

  /**Main method that creates a new JFrame
    *Adds ShapePanel and does main JFrame methods
    */
  public static void main (String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new ShapePanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  /**ShapePanel constructor that creates a JPanels controlPanel and drawPanel
    * Adds JTextField showNum for display of how many shapes have been created to controlPanel
    * Adds Jlabel count and addShape to controlPanel
    * Adds controlPanel and drawPanel to ShapePanel
    * Sets control Panel to size 100 x 400
    * Makes new ButtonListener called listener and adds the listener to addShape button
    */
  public ShapePanel(){


    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    DrawingPanel drawPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    timer = new Timer (DELAY, listener);

    addShape.addActionListener(listener); //adds a new ButtonListener listener to JButton addShape
    controlPanel.add (addShape); //controlPanel adding
    controlPanel.add (showNum);
    controlPanel.add (countLabel);
    controlPanel.add(start);
    controlPanel.add(stop);
    add (controlPanel); 
    add (drawPanel);


    controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400)); 
  }
  /**Inner class of ShapePanel that determines action of button being pressed
    *Converts count to string totalCount and sets JTextField to count
    *Creates a new shape every time button is pressed and increments count
    */

  /**Inner class DrawingPanel which contains a constructor and paint method
    */

  private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{
    /**Contructor that is set to a size of 400 x 400 pixels
      *Background is set to pink
      */
    public DrawingPanel(){
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
      setBackground(Color.pink);

    }

    /**paintComponent method which calls the paintComponenet method from JPanel
      * For every shape that has been created, it calls the display method with graphics object g from Shape class
      * Once display method is called, the repaint method is called
      */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent (g);
      for (int index = 0; index< count; index ++){

        shapes[index].display(g);
      }
      repaint();
    } //end of paintComponent
  } //end of DrawingPanel
  private  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
      String totalCount = Integer.toString(count);
      showNum.setText(totalCount);

      if (event.getSource() == addShape && count<shapes.length){
        //check that count is smaler than length of array, if so add new Shape to the array and count ++, set text of JTextField to display count
        //call the repaint method on drawPanel to update panel diplayed on screen
        Shape shape = new Shape();
        shapes [count] = shape;

        count ++;

      }
        if (event.getSource() == start){ //here is my problem! I want to click the start button and be able to move my objects

          timer.start();

          for (Shape shape: shapes){

            shape.move(); 


          }
        }
        if (event.getSource() == stop){
          timer.stop();

        }
         repaint();
      }

  }

}//end of class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems...

First, you use your `ButtonListener` with your `javax.swing.Timer`, but in the listener, you do nothing to actually update the position of the buttons when the timer ticks.  So instead of...

```
timer = new Timer(DELAY, buttonListener);
```

You should be doing something more like...

```
timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {

            shape.move();

        }
    }
});
```

Second, you don't actually register the `ButtonListener` with the `start` or `stop` buttons, for example...

```
start.addActionListener(buttonListener);
stop.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

Thirdly, you are calling `repaint` within the `paintComponent` method, this is a very bad idea, painting should paint the current state and should do nothing that might otherwise cause a repaint of any kind to trigger, otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop, which consume your CPU until nothing will run...

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the listener to the button:

```
start.addActionListener(listener);
```

You should also avoid using the same listener to do different things. Each button, and each Timer, should have its own listener doing only what should happen when this specific button is pressed:

```
start.addActionListener(new StartMovingActionListener());
stop.addActionListener(new StopMovingActionListener());
timer.addActionListener(new MoveShapesActionListener());
```

You can also use anonymous classes if you prefer. But a single class with a big if/else ladder to know whic button has been pressed is a mess.